# Isometry of surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, isometry

We know isometry of euclidean spaces is composition of an orthogonal transformation and a translation. Also differential map of an isometry of regular surfaces is an orthogonal transformation.
 I want to know that, is there any such composition or some expression for  isometry of surfaces? 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, "If $F$ and $G$ are isometric surfaces is $3$-space, and $u : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ is a map whose restriction to $F$ is an isometry from $F$ to $G$, then does the map $u$ (or its restriction to $F$) have some particular form?" Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes Sir exactly that I want to know.

Comment: Yes Sir, Is there any particular form of map u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no particular form of the map $u$, no. First of all, consider an isometry from the $xy$-plane to itself, one that *fixes* the plane. Then $u$ has the form 
$$
u(x, y, 0) = (x, y, 0)
$$
for any $x, y$. But *off* the plane, it can be almost anything. Letting $f$ be any (continuous) function of $x, y, z$, we can write something that's the "same" as $u$ (from the point of view of isometry) but looks rather different:
$$
v(x, y, z) = (x, y, z f(x, y, z))
$$
Indeed, we could write
$$
v(x, y, z) = (x, y, 0) + z(f(x, y, z), g(x, y, z), h(x, y, z))
$$
and still have an isometry, as long as $f, g, h$ are continuous functions.

Of course, all this depends on $u$ being "messy" away from the surface $F$. Another possibility is that on the surface $F$ itself, the function must be "nice", but even that is pretty much hopeless. For once again letting $F$ be the $xy$-plane, we can write

$$
u(x, y, z) = (x, y, zk(z) + h(x))
$$
where $k$ and $h$ are any continuous functions, and get an isometry (indeed, a *special* isometry that's the identity on the surface $F$).

In short: isometry, for surfaces in 3-space, just isn't very "rigid".

If you require that the surfaces be compact surfaces without boundary, you might find some more rigidity, but even then I have my doubts, for if your compact surface happens to have a 'flat region' (some open disk that lies entirely in a plane), then *within* this flat region, you can do the tricks that I did with the plane above.

Maybe for compact surfaces with everywhere (or almost-everywhere) nonzero gaussian curvature, there's a rigidity theorem -- I suspect there is, but cannot recall it -- but in general, things can be pretty ugly.

Comment: How about  if you try to characterize instead the situation where: you have $F, G \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ two smooth isometric Riemannian 2-manifolds (surfaces) smoothly and isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. And you are interested in $\mu: F \to \mathbb{R}^3$ that is an isometry between $F$ and $G$ (so you really don't care how $\mu$ maps points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ away from $F$), is there a known (nice?) decomposition of $\mu$ in this case? Maybe a map that can be build from rigid transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$, Killing vector flow on $F$ and perhaps other discrete symmetries of $F$?

Comment: That sounds like a fascinating question, but one for which I am not the person to answer. I suggest that you ask it as its own question here on MSE; comments really aren't the place for new questions, no matter how interesting they might be. It's worth remembering that the helicoid and catenoid are isometric, while it's pretty hard to imagine any (even locally) rigid xformation of 3-space carrying part of one to part of the other, even if you throw in discrete symmetries or other natural flows.

Comment: @Jon Hughes Thanks, I've asked a separate question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3316540/decomposition-of-surface-isometry-to-rigid-motion-and-symmetries