# Surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$: decomposition of surface isometry into rigid motion and surface symmetries

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, symmetry

My question is inspired from this older [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704654/isometry-of-surfaces/2704768?noredirect=1#comment6823257_2704768) and the discussion in the comments there.

I know that isometries of Riemmanian manifold form a Lie group. I was wondering if something more concrete can be said in the following case:

- Let $(M, g), (N, h)$ two smooth Riemannian 2-dimensional manifolds (with or without boundary).
- Let $\phi :N \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be smooth isometric embedding of $N$ in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$.
- Consider an embedding of $M$ in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$:
  $$
  \mu: M \to \mathbb{R}^3,
  $$
  which also maps $M$ isometrically to $\phi(N)$, i.e., to the embedding of $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(So really, we have $\mu: M \to \phi(N) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.)

> **My question**: Can one think of such $\mu(\cdot)$ as, necessarily, built of composition of 3 types of maps:
>
> - (i) A rigid transformation of $\mathbb{R}^3$,
> - (ii) a flow of a Killing vector field of $M$ (if exists),
> - and perhaps (iii) a map that realizes other discrete symmetries of $M$ (i.e., other symmetries that do not arise from a Killing vector field).

My knowledge of Riemmanian geometry is rather limited and I'm not familiar with Lie groups. So even if a full answer is involved, I would appreciate any intuition or anyone pointing to problems in the formulation of the question itself, why it is ill posed or why it does not make sense.

Comment: Your question is a little odd as stated, though I don't have time to write a thoughtful response.  For one thing, the typical $(M,g)$ has no Killing fields and no discrete symmetries.  It sounds like what you're really asking is: Given a fixed isometric immersion $\mu_0 \colon (M,g) \to (N,h)$, can one describe all the other isometric immersions $\mu \colon (M,g) \to (N,h)$ as arising from $\mu_0$ together with isometries of $(M,g)$ and rigid motions of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @JesseMadnick Yes, I think this is the idea except that I try to factor in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be able to have a concrete picture. In addition, for a start I'm interested in embedding (not immersion) and if I have a map directly from $M$ to $N$ (without going through $\mathbb{R}^3$) then it is not clear how rigid motion of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is involved. Generally, trying to get a feeling for what is going on, with geometric process applications in mind, I think the restriction to a nice manifold, one that does have killing vector field and also a discrete symmetries, would also be illuminating.